# Orleans - how to use typesafe ids or references?

Tags: orleans

I'm testing Orleans out.
I want to store grain-ids for later use. Is there a way to make the ids typesafe? I want to make it impossible to mix ids of differet types of grains.

Or maybe I should store grainreferences instead? Can grainreferences be typesafe?

Answer (score 0):

One of the overrides of `GrainFactory.GetGrain` have this signature:

```
IGrain GetGrain(Type grainInterfaceType, long grainPrimaryKey, string keyExtension);
```

So you can save the type next to the key, and be able to recreate it later in runtime.